# cannot find custom tool 'T4ScriptFileGenerator' on this system

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, t4

I'm using T4 template to generate .cs file by using another .cs file as an input.
It shows me name of all properties inside the input .cs file.

I am looking the way to update output file automatically when i change something in input .cs file. (because i don't want to save .tt file every time I change something in input file)

One way is to use T4 Toolbox, by setting CustomTool property to 'T4ScriptFileGenerator'.

But when i do that i get error message "cannot find custom tool 'T4ScriptFileGenerator' on this system"

I there any way I can fix that?
Or any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the custom tool was changed to 'T4Toolbox.ScriptFileGenerator' in Visual Studio 2012.

http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/discussions/437168